# How to recreate this preload effect?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, loading

I just surfed the net and saw this ultimate preloading effect, it is the most awesome thing I have seen lately, and my question for you JS Experts out there is, how do i create this?

https://fontface.ninja/

Comment: It looks like they use a canvas to do this. If you know some graphics programming, this shouldn't be too bad to make.

Comment: oh so thats the topic i gotta dive into? Thank you vaughan :) ill check it out. if anybody else still wants to comment a more complex answer to this question feel free to do so i would highly appreciate it

Comment: What part of it specifically are you interested? The entire thing is pretty elaborate and more than someone would probably write for free, but a specific piece might be viable.

Comment: The part where the mouse drags the window bigger and it stays, the content flows in, no flicker no reload, the window which was just an animation is now part of the content, this part